# Expand a function into a Laurent series about a point?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Take the function $f(z)=(z^2+3z+2)e^\frac{1}{z+1}$

We want to expand this into its Laurent series about $z_0$=-1.

Alright, so I'm a little confused. This converges everywhere but -1, which throws me off. My first thought is to just start expanding it using properties that I know. So, I think we have the following:

$e^z=1+z+\frac{1}{2!}z^2+\frac{1}{3!}z^3+...$

$\frac{1}{1-(-z)}=1-z+z^2-z^3+z^4-...$

But I'm not sure how to expand the term $e^\frac{1}{z+1}$. It seems like a composition of expansions. Also, can I use a substitution to account for the point -1? This seems like it's going to turn out very messily. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just write, for $z\neq-1$,
$$e^{\large\frac1{z+1}}=1+\frac1{(z+1)}+\frac1{2!(z+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n!(z+1)^n}+\cdots
$$ and 
$$
(z^2+3z+2)=(z+1)^2+(z+1)
$$ then expand
$$
\left((z+1)^2+(z+1)\right)\times\left(1+\frac1{(z+1)}+\frac1{2!(z+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n!(z+1)^n}+\cdots\right)
$$ Can you take it from here?

---

Set $X=z+1$, you get
$$
\begin{align}
(X^2+X)\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}\frac1{X^n}&=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}\frac1{X^{n-2}}+\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}\frac1{X^{n-1}}\\\\
&=\sum_{-2}^{\infty}\frac1{(n+2)!}\frac1{X^{n}}+\sum_{-1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n+1)!}\frac1{X^{n}}\\\\
&=\frac1{X^{-2}}+\sum_{-1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{(n+2)!}+\frac1{(n+1)!}\right)\frac1{X^{n}}\\\\
&=\frac1{X^{-2}}+\sum_{-1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n+1)!}\left(\frac1{(n+2)}+1\right)\frac1{X^{n}}\\\\
&=\frac1{X^{-2}}+\sum_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{n+3}{(n+2)!}\frac1{X^{n}}\\\\
&=\sum_{-2}^{\infty}\frac{n+3}{(n+2)!}\frac1{X^{n}}
\end{align}
$$ Then the Laurent series expansion of your function is

> $$
> (z^2+3z+2)e^{\large \frac{1}{z+1}}=\sum_{-2}^{\infty}\frac{n+3}{(n+2)!}\frac1{(z+1)^{n}},\quad z\neq-1.
> $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance! I think I'm missing a fundamental piece of knowledge - how does the term $z_0=-1$ actually come into play using this notation?

Comment: @Taylor This way:$z-z_0=z-(-1)=z+1$. Thanks!

Comment: Oh that makes sense! So all I have to do is foil out the product, and that produces a Laurent series expansion about $z_0=-1$? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Taylor You are welcome. Maybe, if you put $X=\frac1{z+1}$, things will be clearer to finish the computation.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking one more clarifying question, how is this different from expanding the series $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ about the point $z_0=-1$? Wouldn't that result in the same expansion? This makes me think the expansion should be $e^{\frac{1}{z+1}}=1+\frac{1}{z}+...$, which looks like the expansion of $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ at 0. Can you enlighten me? @Olivier

Comment: No problem :) You may recall that a Laurent expansion near $z=z_0$ is of the form $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=-p}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n=\frac{a_{-p}}{(z-z_0)^p}+...+a_0+...+a_n(z-z_0)^n+...$. If you are near $z_0=0$ then you have a series with terms like $\frac{a_{-p}}{(z-z_0)^p}=\frac{a_{-p}}{(z-0)^p}=\frac{a_{-p}}{z^p}$, **but** if you are near $z_0=-1$ you obtain terms of the form $\frac{a_{-p}}{(z-z_0)^p}=\frac{a_{-p}}{(z-(-1))^p}=\frac{a_{-p}}{(z+1)^p}$. Near $z_0=-1$ you can't have terms like $\frac1z$, rather like $\frac{1}{z+1}$. Hoping it helps!

Comment: @Taylor Are you OK with my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what the final summation looks like? I'm having trouble expressing it from 0 to infinity. @Olivier

Comment: @Taylor I've provided some details :)